# Neo4J cypher:recommend products using NOT clause or any

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cql

I am able to create relationship between material and the enduser who bought it using below code
but now I want to find materials not bought by enduser using materials in common and show as recommendation engine in graph. lets say A bought 1,2,3 products and B bought 1,3 products,c has 5, here I want to recommend product 2 to B customer and c with no products as c and rest doesnt have product in common to recommend

```
 MATCH(f:material),(t:enduser) WHERE NOT (f)-[:BOUGHT]->(t) return f,t
```

I tried using Not clause but its showing all products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would approach the problem.

Assuming the following graph (based on the scenario you have given):

[image]

To recommend materials for user b:

```
MATCH (user:EndUser{name:'b'})-[:BOUGHT]->(:Material)<-[:BOUGHT]-(someOtherUser:EndUser)-[:BOUGHT]->(m:Material)
WHERE
    NOT((user)-[:BOUGHT]->(m))
    AND user <> someOtherUser
RETURN m
```

Which would get the result:

[image]

And similarly, should we try with USER-C we would get:

```
MATCH (user:EndUser{name:'c'})-[:BOUGHT]->(:Material)<-[:BOUGHT]-(someOtherUser:EndUser)-[:BOUGHT]->(m:Material)
WHERE
    NOT((user)-[:BOUGHT]->(m))
    AND user <> someOtherUser
RETURN m
```

We get an empty result as expected:

[image]

**Some Explanation on the cypher:**

`(user:EndUser{name:'b'})-[:BOUGHT]->(:Material)<-[:BOUGHT]-(someOtherUser:EndUser)-[:BOUGHT]->(m:Material)` part first matches the user we are trying to recommend a `:Material` to and the goto the materials he/she has bought, then for each material we are trying to find another `:EndUser` who has also `:BOUGHT` the material. Then for each of them we go-to through their `:BOUGHT` relationships as well and call these materials we find as `m`.

Then `NOT((user)-[:BOUGHT]->(m))` tries to make sure that the user (we trying to recommend to) has not bought the item directly and `user <> someOtherUser` section checks the user and the other `:User` node we have found during processing are not the same nodes (though loops for instance).

**How to use it inside your code:**

You typically would use [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-string-literal) for the values needed (`name` in this example).

simple example in python:

```py
. . .

@staticmethod
def _create_recommendation_transaction(tx, name):
    result = tx.run(
    """
    MATCH (user:EndUser{name: $name })-[:BOUGHT]->(:Material)<-[:BOUGHT]-(someOtherUser:EndUser)-[:BOUGHT]->(m:Material)
    WHERE
       NOT((user)-[:BOUGHT]->(m))
       AND user <> someOtherUser
    RETURN m
    """, name=name)
 
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you @Tibebes. M . this worked for me. I am working for large datasets of 124k records and this helped me a lot.